# Missing required parameters for Route despite displaying id in the URL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am having a slight issue - I am receiving the following error message: `Missing required parameters for [Route: teachers.forums.show] [URI: teachers/forums/{forum}]`

I know what this means. However, I am not seeing where I am going wrong. I'm obviously overlooking something. I've tried what has been posted on other similar questions, but to no avail.

The URL displays correctly in the URL, e.g. teachers/forums/91. I have data against $forum - everything else is printing on the index page and as mentioned the ID is visibly appending to the URL.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'forums'], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', ['as' => 'teachers.forums.dashboard', 'uses' => 'ForumsController@dashboard']);

    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'teachers.forums.index', 'uses' => 'ForumsController@index']);
    Route::post('/', ['as' => 'teachers.forums.add', 'uses' => 'ForumsController@add']);

    // route not working properly!
    Route::get('/{forum}', ['as' => 'teachers.forums.show', 'uses' => 'ForumsController@show']);                    
});
```

**View (blade.php)**

```
<a href="{{route('teachers.forums.show', $forum->id)}}" class="load_more_post">
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right load-right-angle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

**Controller**

```
public function show(Forum $forum)
{
    $teacher = User::getTeacher($this->selectedClass->id);
    $forumQuestionMessages = ForumQuestion::getQuestions($forum);

    return view('teachers.forums.show', compact('teacher', 'forum', forumQuestionMessages'));

}
```

Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: It's not null. I dd it and get a and id - which has a record in the database also.

Comment: Can you add `ForumsController@show` method parameter signature to the question? Something like `public function show(......)`

Comment: Sure - I have added

Comment: Try `php artisan route:list --name=teachers.forums` and see if everything looks good.

Comment: Maybe you cached routes?

Comment: If you did, simple `php artisan route:clear` would help

Comment: Thanks - I ran `php artisan route:clear` successfully, but still the issue persists.

Comment: Can you add the output of `php artisan route:list --name=teachers.forums` to your question.. I'm confused by this, as it should work... Also what is the laravel version?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.3 - I'll run `php artisan route:list` shortly, just resolving some issues with this at the moment

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass parameter to route like this :

```
{!! route('teachers.forums.show', ['forum' => $forum->id]) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but same error occurs with this.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try

```
<a href="{{route('teachers.forums.show', ['forum' => $forum->id])}}" class="load_more_post">
   <i class="fa fa-angle-right load-right-angle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```